# Gstreamer-1.0: mux raw video in a mp4 container

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, gstreamer-1.0

I have a raw video that I can play through gstreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ... autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I can encode this video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ... ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=a.mp4
```

I would like now to put this raw video in a mp4 container "lossless", without any compression. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I can use mp4mux but qtmux accept raw-uyvy. The following works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ... ! autovideoconvert ! "video/x-raw,format=(string)UYVY" ! qtmux ! filesink location=a.mov
```

Answer (score 1):

You answered in your question. Don't do compression

**gst-launch-1.0 ... ! autovideoconvert  ! mp4mux ! filesink location=a.mp4**

But you know, without compression this file will be large (GBytes.)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the source data won't be suitable for re-muxing, but if it is a pipeline such as this should work:

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=... ! [DEMUX] ! h264parse ! qtmux !
>   filesink location=...

h264 data has different "stream formats" and "alignments" that it can be in.  The stream formats are avc, avc3, and byte-stream.  The possible alignments are au and nal.  Different muxers take different combinations of these.  h264parse will make that transformation if necessary.

And to re-iterate, sometimes the source data just won't be re-muxable into the desired container.  It depends on a lot of factors.